# Adding new store, Indexer issue on Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, cron, reindex

By adding a new store in my Magento 2.4.5-p1 EE, the indexers change to invalid status. This seems normal. If I execute a manual indexing via the CLI (bin/magento indexer:reindex), everything goes well because the indexings are obviously executed one by one.

But if it is the Cron that executes the reindexing, the inventory indexer remains blocked for about an hour and the database has a lock.
The problem is that it causes disturbances on the whole of Magento with errors in the logs:
"Could not acquire lock for cron job"
as well as on the app:
"General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded"

I have the impression that two indexing processes are running at the same time on the "inventory" index because of a dependency with the "catalog_product_price" index.

Is it possible to configure the cron job "indexer_reindex_all_invalid" so that it only executes one process, and not two?
Is there another solution to this problem?